# Wordpress slow due to unusual request

Tags: wordpress, optimization

My Wordpress is extremely slow due to a request I have. I tried removing some plugins but no luck. I am using WP-rocket for caching.

Here is my analysis on pingdom where it says a request with xxxx/?version=4.7.3 is slowing down everything
[image: This is my pingdom output]

How can I resolve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off all caching while you are testing. Disable all plugins and see if is still there. If it is still there, it might be from the theme. Switch to another theme and test again. If it was gone after deactivating all plugins, turn them on one by one and test again to see which one adds it.

Another thing to do is to download your whole folder of your site on your computer and then using a [free grep program](https://www.google.bg/search?q=free%20grep%20program) to search for the domain name dentiste-urgence.ca and see if it is mentioned in any files.

This might also be caused by malware. Install the free security plugin [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) and scan your site for malware.

Comment: Thanks. As you said I downloaded the code and found the culpid code by searching for it. Once removed the website loads like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: @Henri Great. Maybe you should accept the answer so other people know it is resolved and not bother trying to help.